# Out of Memory in String Arrays with C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, out-of-memory

I have a string array like this:

```
char **strArray;
```

this array is full and i can print its contents by this method:

```
while(*strArray){
printf("%s\n",*(strArray++));
}
```

This works normally. But when i use this:

```
while(*strArray){
process(*(strArray++));
}
```

I take out of memory error on second string in array. It runs for first string, but fails when goes for second.

Thanks for help!

---

Process method is like below:

```
process(char *line)
{
char *server_id,*delimiter,*outputMessage,*capacity_str;
int capacity;
delimiter = " ";
strtok(line,delimiter);
server_id = (char *)strtok(NULL,delimiter);
capacity_str = (char *)strtok(NULL,delimiter);
capacity = atoi(capacity_str);
curr_server = (server *)malloc(sizeof(server));
curr_server->server_id = server_id;
curr_server->capacity = capacity;
curr_server->full_capacity = 0;
curr_server->next = head_server;
head_server = curr_server;
strcpy(outputMessage , "server added ");
strcat(outputMessage,server_id);
strcat(outputMessage,"~");
strcat(outputMessage,capacity_str);
strcat(outputMessage,"\n");
writeOutput(outputMessage);
}
```

Comment: what is your ``process``? where does it fail using step by step debugging?

Comment: So, things work when you don't use `process` and fail when you use `process`. Hmm... that's a *tricky* one... it would seem to me that common sense would suggest that we need to see the code for `process`. Alas, common sense doesn't seem to be all that common.

Comment: Are you allocating any memory inside `process`? If so, make sure you deallocate it properly.

Comment: I just make some linked list processes inside     process

Comment: @MertŞimşek Please post the code for `process`. Without that, we can't tell you what the problem is.

Comment: `strcpy(outputMessage , "server added ");` You're not allocating memory for `outputMessage`. That means the `strcpy` and subsequent `strcat`s are undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

outputMessage needs to be allocated before you strcpy/strcat to it. I'm surprised you get an out of memory error and not just a segmentation fault.